# asp.net builds perfectly locally but fails on devops after adding signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, build, azure-devops

The errors I get.

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Hubs\FiscalAttestsHub.cs;linenumber=9;columnnumber=24;code=CS0234;]The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Hubs\FiscalAttestsHub.cs(9,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Startup.cs(2,24): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Startup.cs;linenumber=2;columnnumber=24;code=CS0234;]The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Startup.cs(2,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SignalR' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Hubs\FiscalAttestsHub.cs(14,37): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Hub<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Hubs\FiscalAttestsHub.cs;linenumber=14;columnnumber=37;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'Hub<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Hubs\FiscalAttestsHub.cs(14,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Hub<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[warning]\Mail\Models\PaymentReceivedMM.cs(100,23): Warning CS0108: 'PaymentReceivedMM.TenantName' hides inherited member 'MailModel.TenantName'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Warning;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Mail\Models\PaymentReceivedMM.cs;linenumber=100;columnnumber=23;code=CS0108;]'PaymentReceivedMM.TenantName' hides inherited member 'MailModel.TenantName'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
Mail\Models\PaymentReceivedMM.cs(100,23): warning CS0108: 'PaymentReceivedMM.TenantName' hides inherited member 'MailModel.TenantName'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Controllers\Identity\AccountController.cs(59,17): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Controllers\Identity\AccountController.cs;linenumber=59;columnnumber=17;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\Identity\AccountController.cs(59,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Controllers\Identity\ManageController.cs(72,17): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Controllers\Identity\ManageController.cs;linenumber=72;columnnumber=17;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\Identity\ManageController.cs(72,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Models\Identity\AppRoleManager.cs(16,61): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Models\Identity\AppRoleManager.cs;linenumber=16;columnnumber=61;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Models\Identity\AppRoleManager.cs(16,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs(21,97): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs;linenumber=21;columnnumber=97;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs(21,97): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs(13,61): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs;linenumber=13;columnnumber=61;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Models\Identity\AppSigninManager.cs(13,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Models\Identity\AppUserManager.cs(24,93): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[debug]Processed: vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=D:\a\1\s\Models\Identity\AppUserManager.cs;linenumber=24;columnnumber=93;code=CS0246;]The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Models\Identity\AppUserManager.cs(24,93): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOwinContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\.csproj]

[error]\Models\Identity\ManageViewModels.cs(37,22): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationDescription' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Somehow the signalR package was no longer in the list of installed nugget packages, nevertheless local build was perfectly fine and running the app too.

solution : re-add the nuget packages and now build on azure is fine too.